# Let G be a multiplicative group and let H be a subgroup with index $|G:H| = 2$. Show that H contains the commutator subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a multiplicative group and let H be a subgroup with index $|G:H| = 2$. Show that H contains the commutator subgroup $[G,G]:= <s>$ of G, where 
$$S:=\{g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}g_1g_2|g_1,g_2 \in G\}$$

Can someone give me some hints on how I can do this question? What theorems are useful here?

Comment: you can use the following general fact: if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is abelian, then $[G, G] \subset N$.

Comment: @Krish: Why not writing this as an answer?

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: Sorry, I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: Let $G$ be a group and let $G' := [G, G]$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is abelain then $G' \subseteq N$. Conversely, if $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $G' \subseteq N$ then $N$ is normal in $G$ and $G/N$ is abelian.

Solution: Let $N$ be normal in $G$ and $G/N$ is abelian. Then, for each $x, y \in G$, $(xN)(yN) = (yN)(xN) \Rightarrow x^{-1}y^{-1}xy \in N \Rightarrow G' \subseteq N.$ Conversely, let $N$ be subgroup such that $G' \subseteq N$. Now $G'$ is normal in $G$ and $G/G'$ is abelian (why?). Thus $N/G'$ is normal in $G/G'$. Using isomorphism theorems, $N$ is normal in $G$ and $G/N \cong (G/G')/(N/G')$ is abelian, being quotient of an abelian group.

Comment: why is N/G' normal in G/G' and N normal in G?

Comment: $G/G'$ is abelian, so every subgroup is norrmal. to prove $N$ is normal in $G$, you need to use 4th isomorphism theorem for groups (also called lattice isomorphism theorem).

Comment: why is N/G' a subgroup of G/G' when G' is a subgroup of N

Comment: if $G$ is a group and $K \subseteq H \subseteq G$ are subgroups of $G$ with $K$ normal in $G$, then $H/K$ is a subgroup of $G/K$. this you can check by using the definition of quotient groups.

Comment: ok so now i just have to show that G/H is abelian for this question?

Comment: First you have to show that $H$ is normal.

Comment: yup that one i know